# В чем отличие функций count и sizeof

Tags: php

В интернете нашел информацию что sizeof просто псевдоним count'a

Так просто не может быть я не верю! Зачем эти две функции нужны, 100% есть разница!

Comment: А чем вас смущают псевдонимы. они облегчают жизнь при переходе с одних языков на другие. И во многих языках делают псевдонимы, что бы они назывались так же как в других языках.

Answer (score 5):

Это синонимы, они абсолютно одинаковы

Если глянуть в исходники
[**ext/standard/basic_functions.c**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L3347)

```
PHP_FALIAS(sizeof,              count,                                  arginfo_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно есть! Они пишутся по разному.

[Не забывайте про документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sizeof.php):

> sizeof — Псевдоним count()